# Fine Uploader - This is an unrecoverable error, we must restart the upload entirely on the next retry attempt

Tags: fine-uploader

Using Fine Uploader 5.0.6 i am trying to send both the original and scaled image onto my s3 bucket. it works until i set a minimum size limit with `minSizeLimit` in the validation options. When i leave this out or uncomment it it works fine but when it's in i get this output in my console:

```
POST http://zippi.bucket.artist.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ 400 (Bad Request)
[Fine Uploader 5.0.6] This is an unrecoverable error, we must restart the upload entirely on the next retry attempt.
```

I have `retry:EnableAuto:true` so this runs through 3 times with the same result until stopping. This only applies to the scaled image, the main image uploads fine without issue

My signature.php page does not include any references to a minimum file size, just maximum in

```
$expectedMaxSize = 10000000;
```

In this function below. Could this be causing it?:

```
function isPolicyValid($policy) {
    global $expectedMaxSize, $expectedBucketName;
    $conditions = $policy["conditions"];
    $bucket = null;
    $parsedMaxSize = null;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($conditions); ++$i) {
        $condition = $conditions[$i];
        if (isset($condition["bucket"])) {
            $bucket = $condition["bucket"];
        }
        else if (isset($condition[0]) && $condition[0] == "content-length-range") {
            $parsedMaxSize = $condition[2];
        }
    }

    return $bucket == $expectedBucketName && $parsedMaxSize == (string)$expectedMaxSize;
}
```

Code on my actual page:

```
var manualuploader = jQuery("#fine-uploader").fineUploaderS3({
    request: {
        endpoint: 's3.bucket.files.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
        accessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    },
    signature: {
        endpoint: 'signature.php'
    },
    uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint: 'success.php'
    },
    iframeSupport: {
        localBlankPagePath: 'success.html'
    },
    multiple: false,
    retry: {
       enableAuto: true
    },
    autoUpload: false,
    scaling: {
        sizes: [
            {name: "web", maxSize: 500}
        ]
    },
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'],
        sizeLimit: 10000000, 
        minSizeLimit: 400000 // THIS IS THE LINE
    },
    objectProperties: {
        key: function (fileId) {
            var filename = jQuery('#fine-uploader').fineUploader('getName', fileId);
            var uuid = jQuery('#fine-uploader').fineUploader('getUuid', fileId);
            var ext = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            folder_name = folder_name.replace(/\s/g, '-');
            var new_filename;
            if (filename.indexOf('(web)') >= 0){
                new_filename = '/the_web_version.';
            }
            else {
                new_filename = '/the_original_version.';
            }
            return artist + '/' + folder_name + new_filename + ext;
        }
    }
    }).on('submitted', function(event, id, name) {

        //....

    }).on('cancel', function(event, id, name) {

        //....

    }).on('progress', function(event, id, fileName, loaded, total) {

        //....

    }).on('complete', function(event, id, name, response) {

    if (response.success) {
        //...
    }

});

jQuery('#triggerUpload').click(function() {
    manualuploader.fineUploaderS3('uploadStoredFiles');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set a minimum file size validation option, Fine Uploader will pass that value on to S3 to ensure it is respected.  Most likely, a scaled image is smaller than that minimum size.  I suggest simply removing this restriction if you are dealing with dynamically scaled images.

Comment: Thanks Ray but the problem is i do need the original image to be above 400kb even though i also create a smaller scaled version

Comment: Please file a feature request in the github repo.  One solution may be to contribute your own `onValidate` callback that rejects the original file only if it is less than 400 kb.  Of course, this limitation will not be enforced by S3, and will not be enforceable in IE9 and older.